# Surface roughness and pressure on the surface

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Does surface roughness impact calculation of pressure distribution or is it simply assumed that pressure = F/A?

Comment: At what length scale? For, e.g., tribology, things like Hertzian contact dynamics are considered. For the window on a vacuum chamber one only consider the pressure difference and area - any roughness has not impact.

Comment: Thanks, I am asking only about macro scales. Could you please explain in brief why?

Answer (score 0):

I'll interpret the question like this - when a surface is rougher it seems to have more area, does this increase the force on that surface from pressure because the area $A$ in the equation $F=PA$ is greater? It's not entirely clear to me whether this is what you're asking about. But the question has a clear answer - no.

Consider this rough surface (please permit me to use a 2d system which is easier to draw, so $F=lP$, where $l$ is the length of a line segment):

[image]

The force on each line segment is $Pd/\cos(\theta)$, but the left side of each triangle provides a force going right and the right side provides a force going left, so only the downward components remain, which is $Pd\cos\theta/\cos\theta=Pd$. So the net force on this rough wall is $PNd$, the same result you would get if you just totally ignored the roughness.

Incidentally this is the same reason that an enclosed box in a gas with pressure feels no net force although each wall of the box experiences a force.